# How to use custom file names in Laravel migrations?

Tags: php, laravel, file, migration, filenames

I want shorter names for my migration files.
This project will not have tens of thousands of migrations, therefor `2019_11_05_191747_create_units_table.php` is verbose.

I want to have clean migration file names like:
`0001_create_users_table.php`
`0002_create_units_table.php`

But the code in `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator.php` is exploding on `_` and not liking it.
`Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError  : Class '' not found`

How to get this done?

Comment: Don't! [K.I.S.S](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)

Comment: You'll end up writing a lot of code to override the default behavior, which defeats the purpose of "clean"

Comment: Laravel is using date prefixes instead of incrementing numbers to prevent issues if you work more than one developer in project. You could have more than one developer working on separate branches that both use the same number.

Comment: By the way, this has been suggested in [laravel/ideas#220](https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/220) and rejected, you can read there for convincing reasons as to why you shouldn't do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't because you should not change Laravel main core (for update compatibility reasons)

You should use the migrations as intended with "YYYY_MM_DD_HHMMSS_action_table_table_description.php" format.

Well, there is a solution, which would be to create a custom command and do what laravel migration does but with another file format and that's a lot of work for just the name of the migration files.

Comment: `can't` is misleading, we definitely can do it if we want to but we shouldn't

Comment: that's why i said `can't because {raison}` it's not even a should not, if you want the updates, you just can't

Comment: Well the updates shouldn't affect this at all, you can still override in the main application under version control without touching `vendor` folder, I have done this before in [laravel-api](https://github.com/CaddyDz/laravel-api)

Comment: @Saly3301 basicly it's the same as the solution i mentioned but in a package.

Comment: didn't even check it, that's not a package, it's a Laravel app template and it does not use commands

Comment: in case of a migration, you should use a secure trigger, what's better than a command.